# Can I really change standard operator priorities in ALGOL 68?

Tags: history, algol

In Algol 68, I can declare the priority (precedence) of an operator-symbol:

```
    prio @ = 5;
```

(Higher number means higher precedence).

I can apparently redefine the priorities of built-in operators:

```
    begin
    prio + = 7, x = 6;
    print(2+3x4)
    end
```

This should result in printing the value 20, rather than the 14 that a standard parse would give.

Did actual implementations actually behave that way?  With a quick scan, I see nothing in either the *Informal Introduction to ALGOL 68* nor the *ALGOL 68-R Users Guide* to say it wouldn't.  Still, I find that mutability to be a strange feature.

(I should try it and see but I don't have an ALGOL 68 system at my fingertips right now).

Comment: Somewhat unrelated: In Haskell you can also declare operator precedence, so I had to quickly try to re-define existing ones, but it looks like you cannot do that without also declaring them, so that would need some tricks to make it actually work... not that anybody would actually want to do that.

Comment: Why don't you try with an ALGOL 68 system _before_ posting an question?

Comment: Yes: I believe you can.  Algol-68 Genie is here http://sw.ccs.bcs.org/CCs/g3/index.html and David Holdsworthy's restoration of Algol68R at http://sw.ccs.bcs.org/CCs/g3/index.html.  I'll check  out later and consult my copy of Lindsey and Van der Meulen

Comment: I have GEORGE 3 and ALGOL-68R on a computer somewhere in the basement, but have to dig it out.

Comment: @thebusybee - well, I thought the question might also be of interest to the RC community.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 - "Holdsworth"

Comment: It's implied by 0.2.2.c in the report: "Finally, in ALGOL 68, a **priority-declaration** and an **operation-declaration** permit the introduction of new operators, the definition of their operation and the extension of the class of operands of, and the revision of the meaning of, already established operators."

Comment: By "the revision ... established operators" I understand I can add an overload of (say) '+' between operands of some new mode.  But it wasn't necessarily clear that you could change the priority of an existing operator symbol (and the priority cannot depend on the operand modes).  The *Informal Introduction* adds no such caveat, and of course Lindsey and van der Meulen were careful writers, but nevertheless I wasn't sure I believed it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes you can, and it is also scoped (as you would expect with an orthogonal language like Algol 68). On [Algol 68 Genie](https://jmvdveer.home.xs4all.nl/en.algol-68-genie.html) you get the following result:

```
C:\Users\Brian>a68g SODave.a68
        +20        +14

C:\Users\Brian>type SODave.a68
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    PRIO + = 7, * = 6;
    print(2+3*4)
  END;
print(2+3*4)
END

C:\Users\Brian>
```

Comment: Wow, that sounds as annoying as the `True, False = False, True` annoyance in earlier versions of Python :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo One of my coworkers once redefined `NIL` on a Lisp Machine; it crashed almost immediately. And I hope we all remember that Fortran's pass-by-reference allowed reassigning numeric literals.

Comment: Ooh are we doing this?  I like `#define while if`.

Comment: One of the more esoteric features that no other commonly used language adopted.

Comment: Do you know more information?  Is the effect of these `prio` statements lexically scoped to the containing block? Can it be done module-wide (entire scope of a file)?

Comment: @AdamBarnes: My favorite was `#define EVER ;;`.  It allowed you to do this `for(EVER) { ... }`

Comment: @kaz Scoping does apply as shown in my edited example.

Comment: Concur about the scoping rules.   For "file-wide", that's the same as "program-wide" in Algol 68 as per the *Report* (implementations may have mechanisms for separate compilation), so putting the **prio** declarations after the opening **begin** would affect everything except the standard-prelude and library-prelude.

Comment: @cup: "Commonly used" is definitely subjective, but FWIW, Standard ML lets you do this, too; the expression `let  infix 9 +  in  2 + 3 * 4  end` evaluates to `20`, just like in the OP's example. (The `infix 9 +` declaration boosts the precedence of `+` to the max within the scope of the `let ... in ... end` expression.)

Comment: @ruakh Until your posting, I've never heard or read of ML or Standard ML, even though it came out in 1973.

Comment: A more interesting question is what drove them to do this in the first place. Was there some field where precedence was different from normal? There are several languages that don't have precedence (beyond left to right), but that's a different issue.

Comment: @cup: Fair enough. It's not uncommon in academic CS settings; [an ACM library search for "Standard ML"](https://dl.acm.org/action/doSearch?AllField=%22Standard+ML%22) gets 1,342 hits, which is small but not minuscule. ([Fortran](https://dl.acm.org/action/doSearch?AllField=%22Fortran%22) gets 17,374; [ALGOL](https://dl.acm.org/action/doSearch?AllField=%22ALGOL%22), 6,031.)

Answer (score 4):

This is just an answer to @Will Hartung's query about why priority changes were added.  Say there is a list with two routines

```
ref List ListAdd(ref List ll, int item)
ref List ListRemove(ref List ll, int item)
```

We can code as

```
ListAdd(lll, item1);
ListRemove(lll, item2);
```

Instead of doing that, we can define two operators

```
op + = (ref List ll, int ii) ref List 
op - = (ref List ll, int ii) ref List
```

So we can do

```
lll := lll + 3;
lll := lll - 4;
```

What if we wanted to combine the operations?

```
lll := lll + 3 - 4;
```

Since + and - are the same priority, the order is indeterminate.  It could be

```
lll := (lll + 3) - 4
```

or

```
lll := lll + (3 - 4);
```

If I remember correctly, the default priority of + and - is 6.  There are obscure things that you remember even though you haven't used them for 40+ years. If we want the first case, we could change the priority of + to be 7 so that the + always happens first.

Alternatively, if you do no wish to redefine priorities, do it as two separate statements or just use parenthesis.

Comment: In ALGOL 68 was there a defined (by the language) associativity for operators at the same priority?

Comment: The associated priorities are defined in pg 130, sect 10.2.3.0 of the Revised Report on the Alogrithmic Language Algol 68, http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/ALGOL/report/Algol68_revised_report-AB-600dpi.pdf .  The associativity is not defined.  I remember being caught by that when I went from the Algol68-R (from RSRE, now Qinetiq) compiler to the Algol68-S (from Cambridge Uni) compiler.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize ALGOL 68 allowed you to define operators on data structures.